# How I append data to an array using & in Bash? (now includes answer)

Tags: linux, bash, asynchronous, concurrency

I try to append to an array using & in bash, here is my original code:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a llenar

llen() {
  llenar+=("$1")
  return
}

for i in {1..10};do
  llen "$i"
done
wait

echo "${llenar[@]}"
```

it shows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

but when I use &

```
...
  llen "$i" &
...
```

shows nothing!!! What is the problem here?

*UPDATE*

because I can no longer answer this question, I post my solution here:
Using fifo solves the problem

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a llenar
mkfifo pipe

llen() {
  echo "$1" 
} > pipe 

for i in {1..100};do
  llen "$i" &
done

while read -r line;do
  llenar+=( "$line" )
done < pipe

wait
rm pipe

echo "data : ${llenar[@]}"
echo "data 1: ${llenar[1]}"
echo "length : ${#llenar[@]}"
```

Comment: [If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background **in a subshell**.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html), emphasis mine

Answer (score 0):

Do this modification and you will see the different PIDs

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a llenar

llen() {
  llenar+=("$1")
  echo "$!: ${llenar[@]}"
  return
}

for i in {1..10};do
  llen "$i" &
done
wait

echo "last: ${llenar[@]}"
```